# Does the BIOS of a laptop still work if I upgrade the CPU from dual core to quad core?

Tags: laptop, drivers, cpu, bios

If a particular laptop model's BIOS supports dual core processors with VXT virtualization and multithreading with turbo boost, then will it also support higher-end quad core processors with VXT virtualization, multithreading with turbo boost?

There is no difference in the amount of cores, right? The BIOS sees it as one processor regardless, right? And all of this is handled by the OS drivers in Windows or Linux?

I ask this question because I have a laptop that has a dual core processor and I want to upgrade it to a higher i7 quad core processor that the same laptop manufacturer uses in their higher end expensive models. So would the BIOS work with that?

EDIT:  OK so after thinking about it i suddenly felt If keep the same common drivers for both models: Audio, Bluetooth,  Modem, Camera, Card Reader, Display, Mouse and Keyboard, Networking: LAN (Ethernet), Networking: Wireless LAN, Power management, Recovery, Software and Utility Storage, Touchpad, USB device, Video,

ONLY Intel Chipset Drivers for the two models differ however so i can install the Intel Chipset drivers (Win 7 Win 8 XP) of the higher i7 quad core model on the lower dual core model.

Will this solution work?

Answer (score 4):

No. The BIOS has to support the specific processor model and stepping.

There are also hardware requirements that the motherboard might not meet. For example, the power supply on the motherboard might not be able to support the power a higher-end CPU requires. Laptops shipped with higher-end CPUs might ship with different cooling systems.

Usually, if the same model laptop ships with another CPU, the BIOS (at least) will support that CPU. But not always.

Laptops are not designed like desktops. The power and thermal budgets are much, much tighter. Parts are designed much more as a unit. Motherboards are not intended to support a wide-range of CPUs.

Comment: In this my case both the pros that i want to swap the Intel® Pentium® Processor B980 (32 nm)dual core Intel® Core™ i7-3612QM (22 nm)Processor quad core have the same TDP of 35 Watts so they operate at same voltages currents, power i guess and therefore same cooling systems. So ther shouldnt be any power/heat problems right?  And they have the same socket type too FCPGA988 so that they can be swapped.

Comment: @Decoder: Maybe, maybe not. You can't assume. If the higher-end CPU operates at a lower voltage, that will mean that it draws a higher current for the same power. That can mean requiring a beefier VRM design. Laptops are designed to very tight tolerances.

Comment: Max TDP of 35 Watts in the intel spec of these pros means both pros draw the same power, current rite? and also dual core is 32 nm and the other i7 22 nm so more efficient rite? less power? and also both falls in the max TDP 35 of intel spec after testing by intel And also assuming that the laptop manufacturer (Lenovo G580 in this case) would find it easier to design laptop motherboards in mass production with the same high quality Voltage regulators and sockets and just put in higher components like i7 processors at the end and sell them as higher end models.

Comment: It means they draw the same power. They may or may not draw the same current. More efficient probably means a lower voltage, which means a higher current. This may mean more resistive power dissipated by the power supply that drives it. They probably do design the motherboards the same, but they may not populate all the VRM components on the motherboards for lower end laptops. Or they might find it easier to populate them all so they don't have to stock them separately. You never know. Unlike desktops, laptops are generally designed much more as a unit.

Comment: +1  Also, one cannot discount the simple Greed factor.  As you pointed out, laptops are not designed like desktops, and the manufacturers treat them very differently.  Where a desktop manufacturer may release BIOS updates with increased processor support for newer processors, you will see this VERY rarely with laptop manufacturers.  This is (in most cases) to encourage the end user to purchase a new laptop, as opposed to upgrading a processor.